# Text is not defined

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, artificial-intelligence

I am new coding and I am doing an AI. I have a problem with that print(text), and I can not know how can I resolve that problem.

```
def listen():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print(text)
            voice = listener .listen(source)
            rec = listener.recognize.google(voice, laguage='es-ES')
            rec = rec.lower()

            if name in rec:
                rec = rec.replace(name, '')
                print('Usted dijo: '+ rec)
    except:
        pass

    return rec
```

Comment: What `text` do you want to print?

Comment: Please elaborate your query with complete details. You're trying to record something from microphone. How does text come into play here?

Answer (score -1):

`text` is not defined, you can not print it. A variable must be defined before using accessing/using it.

If your variable is defined outside of the `listen()` function then you can pass an argument to the function. If you don't want to pass an argument then use the `global` (depends on the situation else don't use it) keyword to access it.

Example with the passing argument:

```
def foo(text):
  print(text)

text = "Bar"
foo(text)
```

> Output: Bar

Example with `global` keyword:

```
def foo():
  global text
  print(text)

text = "Bar"
foo()
```

> Output: Bar

Comment: It's best not to entertain the idea that randomly throwing `global` into functions will fix problems (it's much more likely to *cause* problems in the long run).  In your example a much better fix would be to make `text` a parameter to `foo`.

Comment: @Samwise edited my answer, maybe it makes sense now.